# Translating from HOL interpreter to TAC_PROOF with THENL

Tags: sml, theorem-proving, hol

The steps in the `THENL` brackets work correctly if I type them sequentially into the HOL interpreter. But when I combine them with `TAC_PROOF` using `THENL`, I get an error.

I think I understand the difference between `THEN` and `THENL`  (all subgoals versus single subgoal). But I can't find the syntax to differentiate between the 2 initial subgoals. `DISJ1_TAC` and `RES_TAC` should only apply to subgoal1. While `DISJ2_TAC` and `RES_TAC` should only apply to subgoal2.

How can I fix this?

```
val constructiveDilemmaRule =
TAC_PROOF (([],``! p q r s .(p==>q) /\ (r==>s) ==> p \/ r ==>q \/s``),
REPEAT STRIP_TAC
THENL [DISJ1_TAC THEN RES_TAC]
THENL [DISJ2_TAC, RES_TAC]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it. Applying `REPEAT STRIP_TAC` gives two subgoals, so the list argument to `THENL` should contain two tactics:

```
val g = (([], ``! p q r s .(p ==> q) /\ (r ==> s) ==> p \/ r ==> q \/ s``) : goal);
val tac = (REPEAT STRIP_TAC)
          THENL [DISJ1_TAC THEN RES_TAC,
                 DISJ2_TAC THEN RES_TAC];
val constructiveDilemmaRule = TAC_PROOF (g, tac);
```

The first element of the argument list (`DISJ1_TAC...`) is applied to the first subgoal. The second element of the argument list (`DISJ2_TAC`) is applied to the second subgoal.